# Which part of forehead should touch water first when breastroking?

Tags: swimming

When swimming breaststroke, which park of forehead is actually expected to touch the water first?

I fear when my head dips into water, I'm breaking too much. When my head dips under water, which part of forehead should I aim to hit water first? Directly above the eyes, or with more deeper movement, with the higher part of my head?

Comment: For recreational? Or competitive? Competitive you are allowed to completely submerse now during the first phase of the stroke.

Comment: @JohnP for speed... are there any restrictions by swimming championships? I assume they don't apply to open waters/thriathlon...

Comment: Without seeing you swim, it can be hard to tell. But, watching world class breaststrokers, you will see that the head generally stays in a fixed position relative to the torso. It should not be bending back and forth at the neck. Do, the head rises up, you breathe, and it drops back down for the underwater portion.

Comment: @JonCuster and you are correct, that is all driven by hand/body positioning during the stroke. The neck stays relatively stable.

Comment: @JonCuster I have problems noticing small details when there's a lot of action, so it looks I was at false impression I should dig my head into water as fast as possible to minimize the water resistance?

Comment: Watch, for example, Rebecca Soni in the 200 breast (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH7_ekc6ROE), and the other competitors. There is a bit of head movement, but really not that much at all given all the other movement of the body during the different phases of the stroke. Slow it down, stop-frame it, and just look at the head positions.